# Android Facebook sharing is opening shareDialog twice

Tags: android, facebook, share, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-share

I'm using the Facebook ShareDialog to share links and photos, depending on the content. But I'm seeing a strange issue. When I click on the facebook icon in my shareActionProvider, it first opens the ShareDialog with a blank post. Then, when I click to go back to my application, it re-opens the ShareDialog with the link/ photo content I wanted to show.

Here is the code I'm using to share.

```
....

shareActionProvider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(new MyActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onShareTargetSelected(MyActionProvider source, Intent intent) {
           // Recover selected application name for custom action handling
          final String appName = intent.getComponent().getPackageName();

          switch (appName) {
              case "com.facebook.katana":                 // Facebook

                        ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
                                .setContentTitle("Check it out!")
                                .build();

                        shareDialog.show(content);

                        break;

               ....
          }
```

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Thanks!!

I've attached both screens that I'm seeing, in order that I'm seeing them in.

[First screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWfEp.png)

[Second dialog screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqSLw.png)

**EDIT**

I'm adding more of my code.

I'm sharing to FB using a custom `ShareActionProvider` (which is copied exactly from the Android source code, except for me overriding the `setOnShareTargetSelectedListener`)

In my Activity `onCreate`:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
shareDialog.registerCallback(
            callbackManager,
            shareCallback);
```

When I set up my `ShareActionProvider`:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

if (shareActionProvider != null) {
    shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    //... this is before the setOnShareTargetSelected call ....
```

Comment: comment out shareDialog.show(content); Does it still show the blank dialog?

Comment: @Solarnum Now it ONLY shows the blank dialog. Without showing the correct one after.

Comment: hooray! That's your problem.

Comment: @Solarnum Would be nice, except I'm not explicitly showing the dialog anywhere else. So close!

Comment: Can you post more of your code please? Is the button a button provided by the facebook lib?

Comment: no it's a good thing because we know it's not you. If you're not explicitly calling it then something else is and i'm thinking that button already has a share intent attached to it.

Comment: I think you're right, because I set the share intent for the shareProvider when it's initialized. Is there a way for me to remove that shareIntent when FB is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution.

Since I was setting my shareIntent before calling the Facebook ShareDialog, it was being called twice.

In my custom `ShareActionProvider`, I had overridden the `ShareActivityChooserModelPolicy` class. It looked like this:

```
/**
 * Policy that delegates to the {@link OnShareTargetSelectedListener}, if such.
 */
private class ShareActivityChooserModelPolicy
        implements MyActivityChooserModel.OnChooseActivityListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onChooseActivity(MyActivityChooserModel host, Intent intent) {
        if (mOnShareTargetSelectedListener != null) {
            mOnShareTargetSelectedListener.onShareTargetSelected(MyActionProvider.this, intent);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

From [this](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/customizing-individual-share-services-in-a-shareactionprovider-on-android/) post: This class calls the listener, but then returns false regardless. Returning true from this method would allow us to handle the intent, without invoking the default behaviour.

So all I did was change

```
mOnShareTargetSelectedListener.onShareTargetSelected(MyActionProvider.this, intent);
```

to

```
return mOnShareTargetSelectedListener.onShareTargetSelected(MyActionProvider.this, intent);
```

And added `return true` after calling `shareDialog.show(content)`

That solved my issue.

Hope it helps others!

Comment: Can you please explain it bit more? Can you show implementation of `MyActivityChooserModel`

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal unfortunately, I don't have access to the code I implemented anymore (as it was for a previous job).

Comment: Though I believe I just copied the default implementation of the `ActivityChooserModel` class and changed some return values from `false` to `true`. You'd have to check yourself